# How can I parse an array into the json on Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to take the value "maxtemp_c" from the json request, but it didn't work.

This is what I've do, It will block when I try to parse the json and the value is nil

```
//url of the json
let url = URL(string: "http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=6cffef39633d4489a0e101339171811&q=Loria&days=3")!
    let taskfor = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("some error occured")
        } else {

            if error ==  nil {

                do{
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
                    let forecast = jsonResult["forecast"] as? [String : AnyObject]
                    // I would not recommend to use NSDictionary, try using Swift types instead
                    guard let forecastday = forecast!["forecastday"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return }

                    // Check for the weather parameter as an array of dictionaries and than excess the first array's description
                    var finalArray:[Any] = []
                    //now I try to parse the json but the result is nil
                    for result in forecastday {
                        if let dict = result as? [String: Any], let forecastday = dict["day"] as? [String] {
                            finalArray.append(forecastday)
                        }
                    }

                    print(finalArray)

                }catch {
                    print("JSON Preocessing failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    taskfor.resume()
```

and this is the json that I have to parse

```
"forecast": {
    "forecastday": [  //this is the problem that the value is nil
        {
            "date": "2017-11-26",
            "date_epoch": 1511654400,
            "day": {
                "maxtemp_c": 7.3, //this is the value that I need
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "day" key contains Dictionary not Array, just change it to `[String: Any]` from `[String]`

```
for result in forecastday {
        if let dict = result as? [String: Any], let forecastday = dict["day"] as? [String: Any] {
            finalArray.append(forecastday)
      }
}
```

If you want just "maxtemp_c" array then declare final array as [Double] and add a check for "maxtemp_c" in the end

```
if let forecastday = forecast["forecastday"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    var finalArray: [Double] = []
    for result in forecastday {
        if let dict = result as? [String: Any], let forecastday = dict["day"] as? [String: Any], let temp = forecastday["maxtemp_c"] as? Double {
            finalArray.append(temp)
        }
    }
    print(finalArray)
}
```

If you want "maxtemp_c" in [String] format then do

```
finalArray.append(String(format: "%.1f", temp))
```

Comment: use  finalArray.append(forecastday["maxtemp_c"]) if you want maxtemp_c array

Comment: If I want the key separate ? for example my print is [12, 18, 20] and I would 12 18 20 to put in three different label, how can I do it?

Comment: use filter on the array like let only12KeyValue = finalArray.filter { $0 == 12 }, it will return array which you can use by only12KeyValue[0] or only12KeyValue.first

Comment: The values are dinamic ... not static

Comment: You can use for in loop and assign the values to labels for (index, value) in finalArray.enumerated() { switch index { case 0: label1.text = value, case 1: ... }

Comment: UILabel.text must be used from main thread only. I used your method and work but the operation is very slow

Comment: warning says it all, use DispatchQueue.main.async { //put for loop code here }. I suggest you to learn the basics first then dive deeper into other stuff like networking, threading etc.